# Robotframework-WhiteLibrary : Windows app automation : Click button keyword is leading to failure

Tags: windows, automation, robotframework

We are trying to automate a windows app which can be accessed only via Citrix Receiver, using Robotframework-Whitelibrary. I was able to launch the Citrix Receiver successfully. But Attach Window , Click button after that are not functioning. "Could not find a window titled " Citrix Receiver" is the error that is displayed. Without the "Attach Window" command , I wont be able to access any elements inside the application. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Test & Failure information below.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test1

     Launch Application    ${Test Application} 
     Sleep            3sec
     Attach Window    Citrix Receiver
     WhiteLibrary.Click Button    text:Open
```

> | FAIL | AutomationException: Couldn't find window with title Citrix
>   Receiver in process 17020, after waiting for 30 seconds    at
>   TestStack.White.Factory.ChildWindowFactory.WaitTillFound(Func`1 find,
>   String message)    at
>   TestStack.White.Factory.WindowFactory.CreateWindow(String title,
>   Process process, InitializeOption option, WindowSession windowSession)
>   at TestStack.White.Application.GetWindow(String title,
>   InitializeOption option)

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

I had to do the following , Launch & attach the application and then attach window.
After that i was able to find the element in the app.

```
     Launch Application    ${Test Application} 
     Attach Application By Id    ${pid}
     Attach Window    window_title=Citrix Receiver
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@{windows}= Get Application Windows  Locator
${wind_length}= Get Length  ${windows}
log to console  ${wind_length}

#above code to see how many windows are the in the application

#you can use index to switch window

Attach Window ${windows}[0]
#will attach the window in '0'th index
```